# Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PackagePath'. validation script for the argument with value "*path*" did not return a result of True

Tags: azure-devops, biztalk, continuous-deployment, biztalk-2013, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've built a `BizTalk` application. My Build creates a `.zip` file of artifacts. I'm using Deploy **BizTalk Server Application** task in Deployment Pipeline

[image: Deployment Pipeline].

I've encountered the following error

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PackagePath'. The " Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf' " validation script for the argument with value "C:\Agent_work\r1\a\CICD-ZIP\drop" did not return a result of True

Any help/suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Do you solve this issue after specifying the file?

Answer (score 0):

The error message stems from the fact that the path provided is a directory, not a path to a file within that directory. You may need to specify the expected file name of the actual package.

Answer (score 0):

It uses Test-Path PowerShell script:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory)] [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf' })]
        [string] $PackagePath,
```

This command checks whether the path stored in the **$PackagePath** variable leads to a **file**, so you need to specify the **file path**.